# on the determination of a quadratic form from its isotropy group in char. 2

Tags: quadratic-forms, linear-algebra, gr.group-theory

So this question is a continuation of the following one

[1] [On the determination of a quadratic form from its isotropy group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87751/on-the-determination-of-a-quadratic-form-from-its-isotropy-group)

For some motivations and relevant backgrounds related to this question see K. Conrad's answer in [1].

So let $K$ be a field of characteristic $2$ and let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space
over $K$. Recall that a function $Q:V\rightarrow K$ is a quadratic form on $V$ if

(1) $Q(av)=a^2v$ for all $a\in K$ and $v\in V$,

(2) $(v,w)\mapsto B(v,w):=(Q(v+w)-Q(v)-Q(w))$ is a $K$-bilinear form.

Define $O(Q):=\{A\in GL(V):Q(Av)=Q(v)\;\;\mbox{for all $v\in V$}\}$ to be the
isotropy group of $Q$ (or isometry group of $Q$).

We say that $Q$ is *non-degenerate* if $Q(v)=0$ **and** $B(v,V)=0$ imply that
$v=0$.

> Q: If $Q$ and $Q'$ are non-degenerate quadratic forms on $V$ and $O(Q)=O(Q')$ does this
>   imply that there exists $\lambda\in K^{\times}$ such that $Q=\lambda Q'$ (in such a case we say that $Q$ and $Q'$ are associated)?

Note that the answer is positive if $char(K)\neq 2$. So you may try to complete
K. Conrad's argument (which breaks down when $char(K)=2$) or you may try to provide an example of two non-degenerate non-associated quadratic forms $Q$ and $Q'$ such that $O(Q)=O(Q')$.

Answer (score 3):

My recent paper with A. Ruozzi includes a proof of this statement that covers the characteristic 2 case:

[Classifying forms of simple groups via their invariant polynomials](http://mathcs.emory.edu/~hbermud/BR-STAB.pdf)

Comment: See Proposition 7.2 in the published version http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2014.08.057

Answer (score 0):

The theory in general characteristic is covered by [these nice notes of Casselman's](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/siegel/FiniteFields.pdf)

Comment: Dear Igor, this is indeed a nice document but I could not dig the answer to the question